# Magento 2 - Authorize.net payment failed in live mode

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am facing a problem with authorize.net payment gateway method since we are aware that authorize.net has removed md5 and provided a signature Key field. Hence I have implemented the authorize.net patch also. When I have tested with a sandbox account its working fine but with Live credential account, it throws following exception.

```
[2019-04-10 20:32:48] main.CRITICAL: The transaction was declined because the response hash validation failed. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The transaction was declined because the response hash validation failed. at /vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost.php:539)"} []
```

Below is the screenshot of Authorize.Net configuration setting.

If any buddy has the same issue. Please help me.

[image: Authorize.net configuration setting]

Comment: Please check your live credentials configured for Authorize.net

Comment: Hi @RajMohanR
Thanks for your effort and suggestion, I have check our live credential is correct, but still, it's not working.

Please suggest.

Comment: So you are testing after applying the patch right? Can you hide your keys and share the screenshot of configuration please.

Comment: @RajMohanR I have updated the question. Please check.

Thanks

Comment: Configurations seem to be fine. We have to check the payment.log now to identify what the error is exactly

Comment: Have you found solution about this issue?

Comment: Did you got any kind of solution for this as I am also getting the same error log? Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Same Situation 
exceptio.log 
The transaction was declined because the response hash validation failed.

payment.log 
'x_response_reason_text' => 'This transaction has been approved.',
and it also still shows the MD5 hash ?

orders show in admin as not paid